# Left Outer Join on Multiple Tables hides data with selection expert- Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, outer-join, multiple-tables

I'm having trouble with crystal reports in reporting on two tables in a one to many relationship.

---

Example Tables:

**dbo.stock**

```
Barcode   Qty   
12345     3     
11111     5     
22222     6
```

**dbo.sales**

```
Barcode    SalesDate    QtySold<br/>
12345      1/1/2013     1          
12345      1/1/2012     1
12345      1/1/2010     1
11111      1/1/2000     1
```

Tables are linked via

```
dbo.stock Left Outer Join On dbo.sales
```

---

Report configuration:

```
Group 1 Header |
Sales          |Sales.barcode Sales.QtySold
Group 1 Footer |Group(Barcode) Sum(QtySold) Stock.Qty
```

---

The Problem:
Display Sales & Stock (without sales date restriction)

```
Barcode    Sold    OnHand
12345      3       3
11111      1       5
22222              6
```

But when a data range is selected then output removes valid products with sales outside the selected data range. Say 1/1/2012 - 1/1/2013

```
Barcode    Sold    OnHand
12345      2       3
22222              6
```

---

I have a version that works using a sub report but the overhead is far to large to use as the sub-report runs for each line.

Can think of a way around this? (without using sub-reports)

Thanks B

---

System Notes:
Crystal 8.5
Database .dbf file access via ODBC driver

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that even though you're doing a left outer join, you're selecting for a date range in the right-hand table which effectively makes it an inner join. If you've got something like `{Sales.SalesDate}={?DateParameter}` in your record selection formula then remove it.

Instead, suppress the details section using `isnull({Sales.SalesDate}) or {Sales.SalesDate}<>{?DateParameter}` so that only sales in the desired date show on the report. To handle the "Quantity Sold" in the Group Footer, use a Running Total instead of a straight summation for only the records in your date range.

Comment: I have been looking all over for this, as I am a Crystal Reports newbie.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

so you want all barcode information but only the sales which fall with the date range?

try this formula in details
if dbo.sales.SalesDate in {?daterange} then {dbo.sales.QtySold} else 0

Insert Summary to group footer

NOTE: You will probably need to switch to Default Values for Null in the formula editor or account for NULL values in the formula

Answer (score 0):

When you want to join two tables in crystal report with left out join and at the same time want to filter report based on right table e.g. sales.SalesDate>='1-JAN-2014' the join will be converted to equi join
to solve the problem some people suggest to use
(ISNULL(sales.SalesDate) OR sales.SalesDate>='1-JAN-2014')

The above solution only works when there are 0 sales  for stock and you still want to show those stock but what if some stock have more than 0 sales  and sales  date is ON or BEFORE  '31-DEC-2013'. In such situation ISNULL(sales.SalesDate) will not work. to solve such problem you need to  either add command object or create a view for sales table as following

1. Create command object with following sql
         Select stock.Barcode, sales.Salesdate
         from stock left outer join order on stock.Barcode=order.Barcode and sales.SalesDate>='1-JAN-2014'
2. second solution is to create a view for sales as
    create or replace view view_Sales as
    Select * from sales  where sales.SalesDate>='1-JAN-2014'
   and then use the view in the report instead of order table as the right table.